# How the values of array got affected in the following c++ code?

Tags: c++, arrays, function-call

When the following program is compiled, the output is **if break float while break**.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

string s[5]={"if","int","float","while","break"};
string & blast(int i){ return s[i];}
int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
         if( i % 3 == 1 )
             blast( i ) = s[ 5-i ];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
        cout << s[ i ] << " ";
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Attempt:**

```
blast[1] = s[4] = "break"
so, s[1] = "break"
Then blast[4] = s[4] = s[1] = "int"
```

but output doesn't agree with this.

I didn't understand this..
Please help me out.

Comment: Hint: What happens if you assign to a mutable reference?

Comment: `string &blast (int i)` returns a **reference** to the string within the array to which you then assign a new string, e.g. `blast(i) = s[5 - i];` is the same as `s[i] = s[5 - i];` Additionally, if you space your code a little more, it will be a lot more readable (especially for older eyes), e.g `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)` and `if (i % 3 == 1)`, etc..

Comment: Did you possibly want to `std::swap(blast(i), s[5-i]);`?

Comment: Please keep an eye on appropriate formatting. Code gets much more readable that way. I fixed line breaks and indentation for you, still your parentheses follow inconsistent patterns. Having spaces after opening or before closing parentheses is rather unusual, but I don't care too much if you at least keep it consistent (either both or none – and then for *all* pairs the same). Spaces around operators should always be placed.

Comment: About braces: I recommend to place them, even if not needed, at least if an expression contains more than two lines (like the first for loop after my edit), and for *all* blocks of an if-else chain, if at least one of them needs them. There are coding conventions (like MISRA) *always* mandating braces, which makes your code robust e. g. against badly written macros (not very meaningfull, admitted, but perhaps something like`INCREMENT_BOTH(X, Y) ++X; ++Y;`) or against forgetting to place them on adding further expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote yourself you have when `i` is equal to `1`

```
blast[1]= s[4] = "break"
so, s[1] = "break"
```

Thus `s[1]` contains the string `"break"`. After that the array does not contain the string `"int"`. Then this string `"break"` is copied now from `s[1]` to `s[4]` when `i` is equal to `4`

```
blast[4]= s[4] = s[1] = "break"
```